# SQL Server database roles - tables

Tags: sql-server

I try to to find a SQL statement to get an overview of all database roles to table connections. So I am searching for an n:m connection between `sys.tables` and `sys.database_principals where type_desc='DATABASE_ROLE'`.

The goal is to have an overview which roles are on which tables. Can anyone help?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019.

Kind regards

Comment: There is no version **2018** of SQL Server - 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022 are your choices - take your pick ! Run `SELECT @@VERSION` in SSMS if you don't know what version of the SQL Server engine you're running on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.database_permissions` is what you are looking for. You can join that to `sys.tables` and `sys.database_principals` and get all the info you need

```sql
SELECT
  schema_name = s.name,
  t.name,
  per.permission_name,
  prin.name,
  prin.state_desc
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
JOIN sys.database_permissions ON per.major_id = t.object_id
    AND per.class = 1  -- object or column
    AND per.minor_id = 0  -- table only, not column
JOIN sys.database_principals prin ON prin.principal_id = per.grantee_principal_id
    AND prin.type = 'R'; -- same as DATABASE_ROLE
```